# Reuse salesforce Apex methods with iPad client (with pocketsoap frame work)

Tags: ipad, salesforce, apex-code

Some iPad client access my 'salesforce' application via [pocketsoap](http://www.pocketsoap.com) frame work. Can any one please tell me whether that client can invoke (reuse) my Apex service methods with 'pocketsoap'. I have already exposed those methods as a WebServices as follow. Thanks.

```
// Job service 
global class ServiceJob {
       WebService static String jobConfirm(String jobId) {}   
}

// Sample registration service 
global with sharing class ServiceSampleRegistration {
       WebService static Sample_Registration__c registerWS(Job_c job, ID userId) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be perfectly fine — if you go the list of Apex classes inside the Salesforce org you should see a link to the WSDL for your class next to the Edit link. You can use this as the basis for your SOAP calls to the custom web service methods.

Comment: Hi Matt Lacey! Many thanks for your feedback. Can you please tell me, rather than creating new stub (with that Salesforce WSDL) whether I can invoke those remote methods via pocketsoap frame work.